# How to work out the Average of DCounts

Tags: ms-access, dcount

I have recently created a report that shows the number of rows from my table for different yes/no attributes. Now, I would like to add another box that will show the average of these two look ups, as well as the difference between the results as seen on picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like simple math to me (unless I am misunderstanding your "Average" request.

**Difference:**

`=DCount("*", "[Quote Lost Query]") - DCount("*", "[Quote Won Query]")`

**Average:**

`=(DCount("*", "[Quote Lost Query]") + DCount("*", "[Quote Won Query]")) / 2`

Comment: thanks! that was much simpler than i had thought. tried using the totals tool rather than using equations. greatly appreciated.